# .NET Core Audit Logging

Tags: api, .net-core, audit

I want to implement audit logging in my .NET Core application.
Something like

```cs
[HttpPost, Auditing]
public dynamic SomeApiAction()
{
    // API code here
    ... 
}
```

The Attribute should be able to intercept the API call before and after execution in order to log.

Is there any such mechanism available in .net core as a part of the framework? I don't want to use any third-party component.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CustomActionFilter for it like

```cs
public class CustomDemoActionFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
       
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller == null) return;
        var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", "onactionexecuting", controllerName, actionName);
        var CurrentUrl = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName;

       bool IsExists = false;
       if(CurrentUrl=="/Home/Index")
       {
           IsExists=true;
       }
       else
       {
           IsExists=false;
       }           
      
        if (IsExists)
        {
          //do your conditional coding here.
          //context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" } });
        }
        else
        {
          //else your error page
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Error" } });
        }
        //base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }


    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
      
    }
}
```

and just use this customactionfilter as attribute over your action method like

```cs
[HttpGet]
[CustomHMISActionFilter]
public IActionResult Registration()
{
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Audit.WebApi](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.WebApi#auditwebapi)  library which is part of [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#auditnet) framework. It provides a configurable infrastructure to log interactions with your Asp.NET Core Web API.

For example using attributes:

```cs
using Audit.WebApi;

public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AuditApi(IncludeHeaders = true)]
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indicate that you are the author of the framework.

Comment: Yes I am :) but what's the difference if I indicate so?

Comment: It's ok, but you should indicate it. See "Avoid overt self-promotion": https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior